# How can I speed up the solving of this specific equation

Tags: equation-solving

I'm trying to work on solving the Jiles-Atherton model of magnetic hysteresis, so I'm using the following equations, as found in this paper (Jaafar, 2013)

[image: Equation of Jiles atherton model]

The mathematica code intended to solve 1 time step is as follows

```
Subscript[M, s] = 1.7*10^6;
a = 1000;
c = 0.1;
k = 2000;
\[Alpha] = 0.001;
H[t_]:=(4*10^-5 + 0.1 Sin[2 \[Pi] t])
dH[t_] := \[Pi]/5 Cos[2 \[Pi] t]

NSolve[{
   He[t] == H[t] + \[Alpha] M[t],
   Man[t] == Subscript[M, s] (Coth[He[t]/a] - a/He[t]),
   (Mirr[t] - Mirr[t - 1])/(H[t] - H[t - 1]) == (Man[t] - Mirr[t])/(
    k Sign[dH[t]]),
   (M[t] - M[t - 1])/(
    H[t] - H[t - 1]) == (1 - c) (Man[t] - Mirr[t])/(
      k Sign[dH[t]] - \[Alpha] (Man[t] - Mirr[t])) + 
     c (Man[t] - Man[t - 1])/(H[t] - H[t - 1])
   }, {M[t], Man[t], Mirr[t], He[t]}] /. t -> 10^-3
```

The code above is iterated from 0 to 1.25 seconds using a do loop. However, NSolve takes very long to solve even 1 time step. How can I speed this up? Any help is appreciated, thank you.

**Update:**
Thanks to Alex trounev for the suggestion. The code I have used is as follows (quite a Naive solution):

```
NDSolve[{
NDSolve[{
  He[t] == H[t] + \[Alpha] M[t],
  Man[t] == Subscript[M, s] (Coth[He[t]/a] - a/He[t]),
  M'[t] == (Man[t] - Mirr[t])/(k Sign[dH[t]]) dH[t],
  M'[t] == ((1 - c) (Man[t] - Mirr[t])/(
       k Sign[dH[t]] - \[Alpha] (Man[t] - Mirr[t]))) dH[t] + c Man'[t],
  He[0] == H[0],
  M[0] == 0,
  Man[0] == 0,
  Mirr[0] == 0
  }, {M, Man, Mirr, He}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

However, this now returns the error:
*NDSolve::icfail: Unable to find initial conditions that satisfy the residual function within specified tolerances. Try giving initial conditions for both values and derivatives of the functions.*
What does this mean and how can I fix this error?

Comment: I don't think that this system can be simpified, I ran it through both `Simplify` and `FullSimplify` and there is no simplification.

Comment: We can't solve this system of delayed equations using `NSolve`.  It  could be better to solve original differential equation (9) using `NDSolve`.

Comment: Please, pay attention that `H[t] - H[t - 1]=0`. In this regards it could be better to use  `H[t]-H[t-dt]`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. NDSolve returns the error: NDSolve::idelay: Initial history needs to be specified for all variables for delay-differential equations. I'm not sure what this means

Comment: The equation `Man[t] == Subscript[M, s] (Coth[He[t]/a] - a/He[t])` does not agree with your initial conditions at `t -> 0`. If you substitute the initial conditions in this equation, it reduces to `0 == 0.025332`. That's the problem.

Comment: @Ky0210 You have a typo in you second code, Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 differential equations only therefore solution to this problem is given by

```
Subscript[M, s] = 1.7*10^6;
a = 1000;
c = 0.1;
k = 2000;
\[Alpha] = 0.001;
H[t_] := (4*10^-5 + 0.1 Sin[2 \[Pi] t]);
dH[t_] := \[Pi]/5 Cos[2 \[Pi] t]; He[t_] := H[t] + \[Alpha] M[t]; 
Man[t_] := Subscript[M, s] (Coth[He[t]/a] - a/He[t]);

sol = NDSolve[{Mirr'[t] == (Man[t] - Mirr[t])/(k Sign[dH[t]]) dH[t], 
   M'[t] == ((1 - 
          c) (Man[t] - 
           Mirr[t])/(k Sign[dH[t]] - \[Alpha] (Man[t] - Mirr[t]))) dH[
       t] + c Man'[t], M[0] == 0, Mirr[0] == 0}, {M, Mirr}, {t, 0, 1},
   Method -> "ExplicitEuler", StartingStepSize -> 0.001, 
  MaxSteps -> Infinity];
```

Visualization

```
fig1={ParametricPlot[{H[t], M[t] /. sol[[1]]}, {t, 0, 1}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1/2, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"H", "M"}], 
 ParametricPlot[{H[t], M[t] /. sol[[1]]}, {t, 0, 1}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1/2, PlotRange -> {{-.01, .01}, {-.5, .5}}, 
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"H", "M"}]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

**Update 1.** We can reproduce data above using FDM as follows

```
H[t_] := (4*10^-5 + 1/10 Sin[2 \[Pi] t]);
dH[t_] := \[Pi]/5 Cos[2 \[Pi] t];


sol0 = Solve[{(Mirr[t] - 
      Mirr[t - dt]) == (Man[t] - Mirr[t])/(k Sign[dH[t]]) (H[t] - 
       H[t - dt]), (M[t] - 
      M[t - dt]) == ((1 - 
          c) (Man[t] - 
           Mirr[t])/(k Sign[dH[t]] - \[Alpha] (Man[t] - Mirr[t]))) (H[
         t] - H[t - dt]) + c (Man[t] - Man[t - dt])}, {M[t], Mirr[t]}];

M1 = M[t] /. sol0[[1]];

Mirr1 = Mirr[t] /. sol0[[1]];

Subscript[M, s] = 17*10^5; dt = 5 10^-4;
a = 1000.;
c = 1/10.;
k = 2000.;
\[Alpha] = .001; M[-dt] = 0.; Mirr[-dt] = 0.; 
Man[-dt] = N[Subscript[M, s] (Coth[H[-dt]/a] - a/H[-dt])]; Do[
 He[t] = H[t - dt] + \[Alpha] M[t - dt]; 
 Man[t] = Subscript[M, s] (Coth[He[t]/a] - a/He[t]); Mp = M1; 
 Mirrp = Mirr1; He[t] = H[t] + \[Alpha] Mp; M[t] = M1; 
 Mirr[t] = Mirr1, {t, 0, 1, dt}]
```

Visualization together with data shown in Figure1:

```
Show[fig1[[2]],ListPlot[Table[{H[t], M[t]}, {t, 0, 1, dt}], 
  PlotRange -> {{-.01, .01}, {-.5, .5}}, FrameLabel -> {"H", "M"}, 
  Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image: Figure 2]